# How to define that a child should only appear in one scene?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, state

We are making an space impact game. Here are 3 of our classes. Our problem is that when we create our `InimigoNoite`, they appear all over the game(menus, other levels, etc), instead of only appearing in the Scene that we want. How should we restrict the child to only appear in the CenárioCidade?
We've tried to use `gotoandPlay`, `addChildAt`, and also tried to create the Inimigo not in the Main class, but in the Inimigo class itself, but it doesnt appear at all. Please can someone help us? Thank you very much!

**KEY.as**

```
package {

  import flash.display.Stage;
  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    public class Key {

        private static var initialized:Boolean = false;
        private static var keysDown:Object = new Object();

        public static function initialize(stage:Stage) {
            if (!initialized) {
                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
                stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyReleased);
                stage.addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, clearKeys);

                initialized = true;
            }
        }


        public static function isDown(keyCode:uint):Boolean 
        {
            return Boolean(keyCode in keysDown);
        }


        private static function keyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            keysDown[event.keyCode] = true;
        }


        private static function keyReleased(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
            if (event.keyCode in keysDown) {
                delete keysDown[event.keyCode];
            }
        }

        private static function clearKeys(event:Event):void {

            keysDown = new Object();
        }
    }
}
```

**INIMIGO NOITE.as**

```
package{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class InimigoNoite extends MovieClip{

        var speed:Number;
        static var list:Array = new Array();
        var balaTimer: Timer;

        function InimigoNoite(){

            list.push(this);
            this.x = 1160;
            this.y = 150 + (450-150) * Math.random();
            speed = Math.random()*5 + 5;
            addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
            var intervalo: Number = Math.random()*500 + 1000;
            balaTimer = new Timer(intervalo);
            balaTimer.addEventListener("timer", bala);
            balaTimer.start();

        }

        function enterFrame (e:Event){

            this.x -= speed;
            if(this.x < -100){
                matar();
                return;
            }

            if(this.hitTestObject(SpaceImpact.navecnoite)){
                matar();
            }
        }

        function matar(){

            var explosao = new ExplosaoNoite();
            stage.addChild(explosao);
            explosao.x = this.x;
            explosao.y = this.y;

            balaTimer.stop();
            balaTimer.removeEventListener("timer",bala);

            removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
            stage.removeChild(this);

            for(var i in list){
                if(list[i] == this){
                    delete list[i];
                }
            }
        }

        function bala(e:Event){

            var b = new BalaInimigo();
            b.x = this.x -50;
            b.y = this.y;
            stage.addChild(b);
        }
    }
}
```

**MAIN.as**

```
package{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class SpaceImpact extends MovieClip{

    static var navecnoite:MovieClip;
    var inimigoNoiteTimer:Timer;

        function SpaceImpact(){
            Key.initialize(stage);
            inimigoNoiteTimer = new Timer(8000);
            inimigoNoiteTimer.addEventListener("timer", criaInimigo);
            inimigoNoiteTimer.start();
        }

        function criaInimigo(e:Event){
            var inimigo = new InimigoNoite();
            stage.addChild(inimigo);
            addChildAt(inimigo, 3);         
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: We are working with .as external classes instead of actions inside the Timeline.

Comment: roncon222, did you find a solution to your issue?

Comment: yes we did but we used another way. we used a function called enviaInimigo (which is basically sendEnemy) and that function has a counter that defines how many enemies we're sending and a currentFrame = xLayer that defines in which layer the enemies are being draw. https://github.com/IrinaAPropria/space-impact/blob/master/SpaceImpact.as

Comment: Now we have another problem which is basically the same one, we want to define a score String that saves the score of the player, depending on how many enemies he has shoot. however i'm having the same problem, when I define in the main class (SpaceImpact.as) that I want the ScoreCity to appear on (currentFrame == 7), i get an error saying that the index is out of bounder....

Comment: Without seeing the code your using it's difficult to help.  Again though, using frames for anything but animation is generally not a good way to architect your application.

Answer (score 1):

You never stop the timer. So your inimigo is created and added every 8seconds.
Stop the timer in criaInimigo and/or use the timerComplete Event

```
 function SpaceImpact(){
    Key.initialize(stage); 
    inimigoNoiteTimer = new Timer(8000,1);
    inimigoNoiteTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, criaInimigo);
    inimigoNoiteTimer.start();
}

function criaInimigo(e:Event){
    //inimigoNoiteTimer.stop();//only needed if you use the 'timer'-Event
    var inimigo = new InimigoNoite();
    stage.addChild(inimigo);
    addChildAt(inimigo, 3);         
}
```

Comment: The `TIMER_COMPLETE` event will never fire in your example

Comment: Thank you all very very much!

Answer (score 1):

Right when you application starts, you are creating a new `InimigoNoite` every 8 seconds.  Since you are adding them to the `stage`, they will appear over top anything you have on your timeline.

The issue (besides creating them when the application starts and never stopping your timer), is that when you through code use `addChild`, that child will stay on the screen until it's explicitly removed via `removeChild` (or one of it's parents are - but since the parent is `stage` that isn't going to happen).

I see that your have a hit test in the `InimigoNoite` class that can potentially remove it, but I don't see anywhere else where you remove it (so if the hit test never happens, it will never be removed from the stage regardless of scene).

It seem though that the solution to your problem is more advice on how to architect your application.

**Don't use scenes.**

Your best bet is to create a class file for each distinct state of your game. So something like this as a basic example:

1. Main Menu State
2. Game Play State(either 1 game state that encompasses all levels, or one state for each level - or both - depending on how much functionality changes between levels)
3. Game Over State

Make your game state class files extend `Sprite` or `MovieClip`, and if you want you can even create a new `MovieClip` in flash pro and attach the class to that (thereby being able to drop visual assets on the timeline).

So then your Main class would just be in charge of managing states (and any anything else that is global to the application)

```
package{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class SpaceImpact extends MovieClip {

        private var menu:Menu; //Assumes you have a Menu.as class file
        private var game:MainGame; //MainGame.as file
        private var gameOver:GameOver; //GameOver.as file

        public function SpaceImpact(){
            Key.initialize(stage);
            goMenu();
        }

        public function goMenu(e:Event = null):void {
            removeAll();

            menu = new Menu();
            addChild(menu);
            menu.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, startGame,false,0,true);
        }

        private function removeMenu():void {
            if(menu){
                if(menu.parent) removeChild(menu); //remove it from the screen
                menu = null;
            }
        }

        public function startGame(e:Event = null):void {
            removeAll();

            game = new MainGame();
            addChild(game);
            game.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gameOver,false,0,true);
        }

        private function removeGame():void {
            if(game){
                if(game.parent) removeChild(game); //remove it from the screen
                game = null;
            }
        }

        public function gameOver(e:Event = null):void {
            removeAll();

            gameOver = new GameOver();
            addChild(gameOver);
            gameOver.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, goMenu,false,0,true);
        }

        private function removeGameOver():void {
            if(gameOver){
                if(gameOver.parent) removeChild(gameOver); //remove it from the screen
                gameOver = null;
            }
        }

        private function removeAll():void {
            removeGameOver();
            removeMenu();
            removeGame();
        }
    }
}
```

then, your game state for example:
**MainGame.as**

```
package{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    public class MainGame extends MovieClip {

        private var inimigoNoiteTimer:Timer;

        public function MainGame() {
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage, false, 0, true); //don't do anything until this object has been added to the screen
        }

        private function addedToStage(e:Event):void {
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);

            //start spawning
            inimigoNoiteTimer = new Timer(8000);
            inimigoNoiteTimer.addEventListener("timer", criaInimigo);
            inimigoNoiteTimer.start();
        }

        function criaInimigo(e:Event){
            var inimigo = new InimigoNoite();
            addChild(inimigo);       
        } 

        //when whatever happens that makes your game finished
        function gameComplete():void {
            dispatchEvent(new Event(addEventListener.COMPLETE));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In addition to what @Batman said, your main timeline should be empty - you should have exported symbols in the library and load them / destroy them as you switch among screens of your game. Don't use scenes for any reason - build out screens on the fly when you need them and discard them once you don't.